# shorten url problem using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to change

```
http://localhost/engineering/management/administrator/modules/course/view.php
```

to

```
http://localhost/engineering/course_view.php
```

using htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)\.php$   management/administrator/modules/$1/$2.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)\.php$   management/user/modules/$1/$2.php
```

Works fine for this,

But  for the below url its not working

```
http://localhost/engineering/management/user/modules/data/edit.php
```

Comment: Why bother with the `.php` in the rewritten URLs? Why not just `/course_view`?

Comment: Of course it won't work. How do you expect the second link to be redirected to `user/modules`? It will go to `administrator/modules`, because the first rule will match. You need to have the parameter `administrator` and `user` in the URL, so you know where the URL should point.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code:-

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)\.php$ management/administrator/modules/$1/$2.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)\.php$ management/user/modules/$1/$2.php
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

when you use this one!

```
RewriteRule   (.*)_(.*)\.php  management/administrator/modules/$1/$2.php
```

because it's possile ro rewrite other URLs(that you've mentioned), you can add special part to it to avoid such thing. e.g:

```
RewriteRule   swd(.*)_(.*)\.php  management/administrator/modules/$1/$2.php
```

and url:

```
http://localhost/engineering/swdcourse_view.php
```

and for second one, use other characters than `swd`!!

```
RewriteRule   ^usr(.*)_(.*)\.php$  management/user/modules/$1/$2.php
```